# Append to element is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following HTML:

```
<textarea class="input" placeholder="Tap to enter message" maxlength="160"></textarea>
<div class="keyboard">
<ul id="special">
    <li data-letter="!">!</li>
    <li data-letter="?">?</li>
    <li data-letter=",">,</li>
    <li data-letter=":">:</li>
    <li data-letter=";">;</li>
</ul>

<ul id="first">
    <li data-letter="q">q</li><li>1</li>
    <li data-letter="w">w</li><li>2</li>
    <li data-letter="e">e</li><li>3</li>
    <li data-letter="r">r</li><li>4</li>
    <li data-letter="t">t</li><li>5</li>
    <li data-letter="y">y</li><li>6</li>
    <li data-letter="u">u</li><li>7</li>
    <li data-letter="i">i</li><li>8</li>
    <li data-letter="o">o</li><li>9</li>
    <li data-letter="p">p</li><li>0</li>    
</ul>

<ul id="second">
    <li data-letter="a">a</li>
    <li data-letter="s">s</li>
    <li data-letter="d">d</li>
    <li data-letter="f">f</li>
    <li data-letter="g">g</li>
    <li data-letter="h">h</li>
    <li data-letter="j">j</li>
    <li data-letter="k">k</li>
    <li data-letter="l">l</li>              
</ul>

<ul id="third">
    <li id="caps" class="pointer">&#8679;<span id="underline" class="color">_</span></li>
    <li data-letter="z">z</li>
    <li data-letter="x">x</li>
    <li data-letter="c">c</li>
    <li data-letter="v">v</li>
    <li data-letter="b">b</li>
    <li data-letter="n">n</li>
    <li data-letter="m">m</li>
    <li><img src="backspace.png"></li>
</ul>

<ul id="fourth">
    <li class>?123</li>
    <li>,</li>
    <li>&emsp;</li>
    <li>.</li>
    <li><img src="search.png"></li>
</ul>
```

with the following javascript:

```
$('.keyboard ul li').click(function() {
  var data = $(this).data('letter');
  $('.input').append(data);
});
```

What I want to have happen is when I click on one of the list items, I want the data-letter to insert itself into the input, sorta like an onscreen keyboard. But it isn't working. Can someone help me?

[Here is a Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LvHRr/)

**Update**

[This works now](http://jsfiddle.net/rfuRa/)

My next problem is the uppercase button. When I click the button, the characters turn to uppercase. How would I use the data to inject an uppercase letter into the input?

The final problem is the first row of letters won't inject into the input. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I came up with

```
keys = $(".keyboard ul li");
keys.on("click", function() {
  var let = $(this).text(),
    upperlet = let.toUpperCase(),
    lowerlet = let;
  if (keys.hasClass("uppercase")){
    input.append(upperlet);
  }else {
    input.append(lowerlet);
  }
});
```

Instead of having the `data-letter` attribute for every single list-item, I got the text using this function, and appended it on click. This now also accounts for the uppercase letters as well.

Answer (score 2):

Try the below

Enable Jquery file instead of mootools in the fiddle

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try:

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LvHRr/24/)

```
$('.keyboard ul li').click(function() {
    var data = $(this).data('letter');
    $('.input').val( $('.input').val()+ data);
});​
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/LvHRr/25/ this works fine with append, might as well keep it with append...

Comment: I would've said that for a textarea really you should be using `.val()` rather than `.html()` _or_ `.append()`.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is remove the margin on the .input element (it's offscreen for me), and enable jquery on the jsfiddle.  After that it works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why jquery .data() not work, but you can use below "this.dataset.xxx"

```
var data = this.dataset.letter;
```